# Decipher the meaning of $\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{N}(W_t)]$ and compute its value

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I encounterred a question on Stochastic Calculus as following, but I don't understand the meaning of $\mathcal{N}$ here, can any expert explain it?

$\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{N}(W_t)]=?$ where $W_t$ is standard Brownian Motion.

A follow-up is $\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{N}(W_t+a)]=?$ I was also blocked by the meaning of $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: I don't know what is $\mathscr N$, could you put a source for this problem?

Comment: Hi Ilya, I am also not sure about it, it seems it's understandable to many stochastic analysis experts but I am not.

Comment: Hi Ilya, I know how to handle it, $\mathcal{N}$ is just the cdf of standard normal distribution.

Comment: Good. FYI, it is usually denoted through $\Phi$

Answer (score 9):

So... after much discussions in the comments, in the end it seems that the letter $\mathcal N$ is used here to denote $\Phi$ [the CDF of the standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), defined by $\Phi(x)=\mathrm P(X\leqslant x)$, where $X$ is any standard normal random variable.

Since $W_t=\sqrt{t}Y$ where $Y$ is standard normal, $\mathrm E(\Phi(W_t))=\mathrm P(X\leqslant\sqrt{t}Y)=\mathrm P(Z\leqslant0)$ with $Z=X-\sqrt{t}Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent and centered normal, $Z$ is centered normal hence $Z$ is symmetric and $\mathrm E(\Phi(W_t))=\Phi(0)=\frac12$ for every $t$.

By the same decomposition, $\mathrm E(\Phi(W_t+a))=\mathrm P(Z\leqslant a)$. Since $Z$ is centered normal with variance $1+t$, $\mathrm P(Z\leqslant a)=\mathrm P(\sqrt{1+t}\cdot X\leqslant a)$, hence, for every $a$ and every nonnegative $t$,

> $$\color{red}{\mathrm E(\Phi(W_t+a))=\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+t}}\right)}$$

**Exercise:** Use this approach to completely and readily solve this [nearly duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149254/) of yours.