# Integration of normal cdf * normal pdf

Tags: probability-theory

Is it possible to evaluate this expression? $\int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(ay)\phi(y)dy$

If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems very close your question: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7505/calculate-the-expectation-of-a-shift-cdf

Comment: please refer to here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149254/how-to-compute-this-integral-involving-a-cdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at independent standard normal random variables $X$ and $Y$. We have $$\begin{align}P\{X\leq aY\}&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X\leq ay\mid Y=y\}\phi(y)\,dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(ay)\phi(y)\,dy\\&=\frac{1}{2}\end{align}$$ since $P\{X-aY\leq 0\}$ can be evaluated directly by noting that $X-aY\sim N(0,1+a^2)$. You need to integrate only from $0$ to $\infty$ and so I suspect the answer will work out to something like $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan(a)$. Draw a sketch of the $x$-$y$ plane and use the circular symmetry of the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: It turns out this is commonly called the 'ratio distribution'. A worked solution is [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioDistribution.html). The correct answer is, by my calculations, $\dfrac{1}{\pi} \dfrac{1}{(1+z^2)}$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah - and indeed, the CDF is as you say. Or, rather, your suspicion multiplied by two (if I'm correct).

Comment: @user65257 Be careful here.  The event $\{X - aY \leq 0\}$ (or $\{X\leq aY, Y\geq 0\}$) is not the same as the set $\left\{\frac{X}{Y} \leq a\right\}$. The probability of the latter event is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(a), -\infty < a < \infty$ which leads to the Cauchy distribution.