# Integration of the product of PDF and scaled CDF of the Normal distribution

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, density-function

I am trying to calculate the integration
$$\int_C^1 \phi(x)  \Phi \left( \frac{C}{x} \right)dx$$
where $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ are the PDF and CDF of the standard Normal distribution respectively; $0 < C < 1$ is a constant.

Note that this is not the same of this question [another similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339202/integration-of-normal-cdf-normal-pdf) because this is multiplication not linear combination.

I don't know where to start. Any hint?

Comment: I doubt that this can be expressed in closed form.  Do you have any reason to think it can?