# Probability that the product of Brownian motion at two dates is positive

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion, $B_0 = 0$.

$0 \le t_1 \le t_2$

As the title says, I am trying to calculate the following probability :

$\text{Pr}(B_{t_1}B_{t_2} \ge 0)$

Any leads ?

Comment: By symmetry, $\mathbb P(B_{t_1}\geqslant 0)=\frac12$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(B_{t_1}\geqslant 0, B_{t_2}\geqslant 0) = \mathbb P(B_{t_2}\geqslant 0\mid B_{t_1}\geqslant 0)\mathbb P(B_{t_1}\geqslant 0).$$

Comment: @Math1000 got that far.

How do you get the following ??


$\mathbb{P}(B_{t_{2}} \ge 0 | B_{t_{1}} \ge 0)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $s < t$. By symmetry of Brownian motion, we have $$\mathbb{P}(B_s B_t \geq 0) = \mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0, B_t \geq 0) + \mathbb{P}(-B_s \geq 0, -B_t \geq 0) = 2 \mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0, B_t \geq 0).$$ Consequently, it suffices to compute the probability on the right-hand side. Conditioning on $\mathcal{F}_s := \sigma(B_r; r \leq s)$, we find from the Markov property that

$$\mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0, B_t \geq 0)= \mathbb{E}\left( 1_{\{B_s \geq 0\}} \mathbb{P}(B_{t-s}+x \geq 0) \bigg|_{x=B_s}\right). \tag{1}$$

Denote by $\Phi$ the cdf of the standard Gaussian distribution. Since $B_{t-s}$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $t-s$, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(B_{t-s}  +x \geq 0) = \mathbb{P}(B_{t-s} \leq x) = \Phi(x/\sqrt{t-s}).$$

Hence, by $(1)$,

$$\mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0,B_t \geq 0) = \mathbb{E}(1_{\{B_s \geq 0\}} \Phi(B_s/\sqrt{t-s})).$$

If we denote by $\varphi$ the density of the Gaussian distribution, then we can write this equivalently as

$$\mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0,B_t \geq 0) = \int_0^{\infty} \Phi(\sqrt{s} x/\sqrt{t-s}) \varphi(x) \, dx.$$

The latter integral can be calculated explicitly, see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149259/36150), and we get

$$\mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0,B_t \geq 0) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2\pi} \arctan \sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}}.$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{P}(B_s B_t \geq 0)= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan \sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}}.$$

A short sanity check: For $s=t$ both sides equal $1$ - as they should.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Cerberos26 You are welcome.

Comment: @saz Why is $$\mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0,B_t \geq 0) = \int_0^{\infty} \Phi(\sqrt{s} x/\sqrt{t-s}) \varphi(x) \, dx.$$ and not $$\mathbb{P}(B_s \geq 0,B_t \geq 0) = \int_0^{\infty} \Phi(x/\sqrt{t-s}) \varphi(x) \, dx.$$

Comment: @user135520 Because the distribution of $B_s$ is not standard Gaussian but Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $s$.